# Is there a VNC server that listens to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port?

Tags: linux, vnc, vncserver

I am trying to find a VNC server that can listen on a [Unix domain socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) instead of a TCP port (normally 5900).

I have not found any VNC server software supporting this. I do know what domain sockets are and want to use server and client on the same box.  I know it's a weird requirement. I have a *client* for it. I modified one to support Unix sockets.

Does anyone know of a VNC server that supports Unix sockets?

Comment: Isn't there a server configuration setting that controls this?

Comment: @martineau: Is there? I went thru it once. Please, let me know if there is one.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken.

Comment: tigervnc added this option: −rfbunixpath path

Specifies the path of a Unix domain socket on which Xvnc listens for connections from viewers, instead of listening on a TCP port.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to use [socat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socat) to forward a UNIX domain socket to a TCP port.  It is very flexible and lets you forward just about any source to any target.

Comment: Little more clarification. I want to use domain sockets because I need to use vncserver and client on the same host and there is no point in going thru network stack when you can have domain sockets. If I use socat, will vncserver avoid going thru network stack? If yes can you give a short example. Thanks.

Comment: Try this syntax: `socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/vlc TCP:localhost:9999`.  This listens for a client to connect to a UNIX domain socket (at pathname `/tmp/vlc`) and when the connection happens, forwards traffic bidirectionally to TCP port 9999 on host localhost.  See the man page for `socat` for variations.  This does _not_ avoid traffic going through the network stack, but no traffic leaves your host.

Comment: thanks. But I am looking at domain sockets for avoiding network stack.